# Windows 10 Installation with premade user

Tags: windows-10, administrator, media-creation-tool

I am an intern working at a healthcare company where we are about to do a significant hardware upgrade for our employees. This includes new laptops and desktops for over 100 users. Each computer will require a fresh install of Windows 10 pro as well as creation of our admin account on the machine. Is there a way that I can have the windows 10 media installation with a default account pre-configured. I may be thinking about this the wrong way and there may be a better way to do this. I am just trying to find a solution that would streamline the on-boarding process for myself and future employees/interns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily configure multiple machines using provisioning package. In fact you can configure much more things than just user/admin account, but also network settings, configure applications, certificates or setup machine with kiosk mode. The deployment is also very easy. All you need to do is connect pendrive to machine and run setup. Please read more in Microsoft docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-create-package

Alternatively, if you want more simple way, you can create account using powershell command

```
New-LocalUser -Name "NewUser" -Description "Custom description" -NoPassword
```

More info related with powershell here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you!